# How to set integer datatype column data alignment to left?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datatable

I have a datatable in which one of the column is of integer type. Now after binding it to a GridView, integer column data are being aligned to right side of the column, But I want it to be left side as exactly the string type column.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: WPF/WinForms/WebForms?

Answer (score 2):

In a DataGridView you could align a column with

```
 this.dataGridView1.Columns["ColumnName"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = 
                  DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```

Other values for the enumeration [DataGridViewContentAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcontentalignment.aspx)

By the way, if you want to align also the header caption you could use the same enumeration for the HeaderCell

```
 this.dataGridView1.Columns["ColumnName"].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = 
         DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dataGridView1.Columns["CustomerName"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```

Comment: Thanks MSDN, though its a devex gridView, your suggestion helped me to set the alignment.

this.IdCol.AppearanceCell.TextOptions.HAlignment = HorzAlignment.Near;

Answer (score 0):

```
  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="xxxxx" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" DataField="xxxxx"
                    SortExpression="xxxxxx" />
```

-------------------------------------------OR

At rowbound event check for integer value and left align that column .

Answer (score 0):

You can use ItemStyle to align your column

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="yourColumn">
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:BoundField>
```